# I want to fetch file and image in php code from javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

```
jwplayer("vplayer").setup({
sources: [{file:"server-url",label:"480p"}],
image: "server.com/img.jpg",
width: "100%", 
height: "100%",
stretching: "uniform",
duration: "5931",
preload: 'auto',
androidhls: "true",
hlshtml: "true",
primary: "html5",
startparam: "start"
```

});

I want to fetch file and image in php code from javascript code

Comment: Need to give more details about what you're trying to archive.

Comment: This is the javascript code I want to extract from image: "server.com/img.jpg" and file: "server-url" in php variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't able to assign directly to the php variable.
what i have done i my project get the javascript variable value and create a hidden input like(`<input input ="file" class="file" name ="file" value="" >`) and using `$(".file").val(image);` this i get the value.else u need to send those value to another page using ajax

Comment: Can you give me an example, as I am weak in dealing with JavaScript

Comment: what are you going to do with files & image variable??? gonna save it or something else??

Comment: I want to add it to another JavaScript variable

Comment: then i think you need to use ajax method to send it to new page and add it to a new javascript variable

Comment: Can you explain an example.. and I'm really sorry for your  .. but I'm not an expert in JavaScript

Comment: There is a problem that it is inside a variable and I tried and it did not appear

jwplayer("vplayer").setup({image: "server.com/img.jpg", }) ؛